# How to insert document using DBClientBase class in MongoDB C++ driver?

Tags: c++, mongodb, compiler-errors

Instead of using DBClientConnection class, I am using DBClientBase class. I am successfully able to connect to the DB but not able to insert a document.

Here is how my code looks like-

```
DBClientBase *conn = NULL;
string err_msg;
ConnectionString cs = ConnectionString::parse(connString, err_msg);

if (!cs.isValid()) {
 throw "bad: " + err_msg;
}

try {
conn = cs.connect(err_msg);
} catch (DBException &e) {
 cout << "caught " << err_msg << endl;
return 1;
}

if (!conn){
   cout<<"Unable to connect to DB"<<endl;
   return 1;
}

BSONObjBuilder b;
b.append("name", "Joe");
b.append("age", 33);
BSONObj p = b.obj();

conn.insert("db.coll",p,0);
```

the compiler gives error `request for member ‘insert’ in ‘conn’, which is of non-class type ‘mongo::DBClientBase*’`

Is there an example somewhere on how to use DBClientBase class to insert documents?

Also, I cannot seem to find what is the use of flags in `virtual void insert (const string &ns, BSONObj obj, int flags=0)` as mentioned [here](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_base.html#a28696cd9354ec5d2ea197758a47e77f2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

conn is a *pointer* to a `DBClientBase`, you should use `->` instead:

```
conn->insert("db.coll", p, 0);
```